# Find all words of length $k$ in lexicographic order

Tags: algorithms

Given the alphabet $\Sigma = \{1,2,\dots, n \}$ and a parameter $k$ how can we find all words of length $k$ over $\Sigma$ in lexicographic order?

I thought of doing this recursively, but although the task is basic it seems pretty hard to come up with a general algorithm, even when using the last word as a parameter using recursion.

Will be glad for any help

Comment: Suppose that $\Sigma = \{0,1,\ldots,9\}$, and consider the decimal representation of the first $10^k$ natural numbers (starting with zero). Can you solve the problem in this case?

Comment: Oh well thanks, I guess it is the $n^k$ first natural numbers starting from zero presented in base $n$ padded with zeros to the left with $\Sigma = \{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$. Somehow thought this is much more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it either inductively or recursively.

Inductively, you just write out the numbers from $0$ to $n^{k-1}$ in base $n$, adding $1$ to all digits.

Alternatively, you can simulate a counter in base $n$ – that would be faster.

Recursively, you can proceed as follows:

- Generate all solutions for $k-1$, and output them with prefix 1.
- Generate all solutions for $k-1$, and output them with prefix 2.
- ...
- Generate all solutions for $k-1$, and output them with prefix $n$.

Alternatively:

– Generate all solutions for $k-1$.

- For each solution $s$, output $s1, s2, \ldots, sn$.